# Adding Two Edges - JGraphT

Tags: java, jgrapht

I'm using the `SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph` from the `JGrapghT 1.2.0` library. My aim is to create two edges between the vertices `A` and `B` such that `A <-80-> B`. If I do:

```
graph.addEdge("A", "B", 80);
graph.addEdge("B", "A", 80);
System.out.println(graph.getAllEdges("A", "B"));
System.out.println(graph.getAllEdges("B", "A"));
```

I get:

```
[80]
[]
```

Whereas if I change the second line to: `graph.addEdge("B", "A", 81);`, I get

```
[80]
[81]
```

Why can I not create two edges between vertices with the same value?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full source code as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JavaDocs](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/graph/SimpleDirectedGraph.html) on `SimpleDirectedGraph`:

> A simple directed graph. A simple directed graph is a directed graph in which neither multiple (parallel) edges between any two vertices nor loops are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
DirectedWeightedMultigraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = 
        new  DirectedWeightedMultigraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);

// vertices
String u = "A";
String v = "B";

// add vertices
graph.addVertex(u);
graph.addVertex(v);

// add weighted edges
graph.setEdgeWeight(graph.addEdge(u, v), 80);
graph.setEdgeWeight(graph.addEdge(v, u), 80);

// print edge weighted
System.out.println(graph.getEdgeWeight(graph.getEdge(u, v)));
System.out.println(graph.getEdgeWeight(graph.getEdge(v, u)));
```